# Xamarin: UITableView cell images not showing in cell when fetched from the web until the cell is clicked

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin

I want to display an image from a URL to the `cell.ImageView.Image` variable in `UITableView` controller's `GetCell` method. For some reason, the image is displayed only when I click on the cell. It's fetching the image, but the cell is not being updated. The data is an `ObservableCollection`, so I'm not sure what I am missing. Do I need to call any method explicitly?

```
public class PasswordGroupsDataSource : UITableViewDataSource
{
    const string PlaceholderImagePath = "Placeholder.jpg";
    UIImage PlaceholderImage { get; set; }
    PasswordsViewController Controller { get; set; }
    List<Password> Apps;
    public ObservableCollection<PasswordGroup> Groups { get; set; }
    public PasswordGroupsDataSource(ObservableCollection<PasswordGroup> groups, PasswordsViewController controller, List<Password> passwords)
    {
        Controller = controller;
        Apps = passwords;
        PlaceholderImage = UIImage.FromFile("Images/Placeholder.png");

        if (groups == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("groups");
        }
        Groups = groups;
        groups.CollectionChanged += HandleAppsCollectionChanged;

        // If either a download fails or the image we download is corrupt, ignore the problem.
        TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += delegate(object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            e.SetObserved();
        };
    }
    void HandleAppsCollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Whenever the Items change, reload the data.
        Controller.TableView.ReloadData();
    }

    public Password GetPerson(NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        try
        {
            var personGroup = Groups[indexPath.Section];
            return personGroup.People[indexPath.Row];
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error in GetPerson: " + exc.Message);

            //Occasionally we get an index out of range here
            return null;
        }
    }

    public override string TitleForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
    {
        return Groups[(int)section].Title;
    }

    public override string[] SectionIndexTitles(UITableView tableView)
    {
        return Groups.Select(x => x.Title).ToArray();
    }

    public override nint NumberOfSections(UITableView tableView)
    {
        return Groups.Count;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableView, nint section)
    {
        return Groups[(int)section].People.Count;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("P") as PasswordCell;
        if (cell == null)
        {
            cell = new PasswordCell("P");
        }

        var person = GetPerson(indexPath);
        cell.Tag = indexPath.Row;
        if (person != null)
        {
            cell.Person = person;

            if (person.Image == null)
            {
                person.Image = PlaceholderImage;
                BeginDownloadingImage(person, indexPath);
            }
            cell.ImageView.Image = person.Image;
        }

        return cell;
    }

    #region Image Support

    readonly Dictionary<string, UIImage> images = new Dictionary<string, UIImage>();
    readonly List<string> imageDownloadsInProgress = new List<string>();
    readonly ImageDownloader imageDownloader = new UIKitImageDownloader();

    async void BeginDownloadingImage(Password app, NSIndexPath path)
    {
        // Queue the image to be downloaded. This task will execute
        // as soon as the existing ones have finished.
        byte[] data = null;

        data = await GetImageData(app.GravatarUrl.ToString());
        app.Image = UIImage.LoadFromData(NSData.FromArray(data));

        InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            if (Apps != null)
            {
                var cell = Controller.TableView.VisibleCells.Where(c => c.Tag == Apps.IndexOf(app)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (cell != null)
                    cell.ImageView.Image = app.Image;
            }
        });
    }

    async Task<byte[]> GetImageData(string ImageUrl)
    {
        byte[] data = null;
        try
        {
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.NetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true;
            using (var c = new GzipWebClient())
                data = await c.DownloadDataTaskAsync(ImageUrl);
        }
        finally
        {
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.NetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false;
        }

        return data;
    }
    public override bool CanEditRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public override void CommitEditingStyle(UITableView tableView, UITableViewCellEditingStyle editingStyle, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete)
        {
            Groups.RemoveAt(indexPath.Row);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

When I debug it, I can see that the image is being set in the `BeginDownloadingImage` function. What am I missing? Why is the cell not being updated until the cell is clicked?

Note: I was using this from Xamarin Employee Directory Sample.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is preferable that you do not input your whole executing code, but rather a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org). Please consider updating your code to help others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure you can do it that way. I would overwrite your placeholder Image on the Person object and then call ReloadRows from your tableview.

```
InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                if (Apps != null)
                {
                    person.Image = app.Image;
                    Controller.TableView.ReloadRows (new NSIndexPath[]{ path }, UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Even better you could store your images in an NSCache using a unique name (like your personid) after downloading. Then in your GetCell method, look for the image in NSCache using the unique name or set the placeholder image if it isn't in the NSCache.